# Avoid WorkManager to run immediately?

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I have a WorkManager in my mainactivity:

```
   private void startwork() {
        PeriodicWorkRequest work = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(AlarmReceiver.class, 16, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setConstraints(Constraints.NONE)
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this)
                .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("workname", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, work);
    }
```

I'd like to play an alert every 16 minutes.
The problem is everytime user start the app it will show one alert immediately, I'd like to show the alerts only after 16 minutes the user open the app.

```
public Result doWork() {
notify();
}
```

Any ideas how to avoid this alert all the time that user opens the app, I'd like just to reschedule it to 16 minutes from now.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `setInitialDelay` and if you use `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE` when app runs it will replace your previous worker use `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP` instead.

```
        PeriodicWorkRequest work = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(AlarmReceiver.class, 16, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setInitialDelay(16, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this)
                .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("workname", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, work);
```

Comment: I add setInitialDelay and remove setContraints but all time I open MainActivity I still have the alert from worker... Any ideas what is wrong? I left the REPLACE instead of keep cause I'd like to reschendule the worker everytime user open main activity...

Comment: Which functions are called before the notification shows up? Is it `startwork()` -> `doWork()` -> showing of notification? If `doWork()` is called before `startwork()`, perhaps there's still a rogue WorkRequest; try deleting the app.

Comment: `startwork()` is inside `protected void onCreate` in MainActivity. and I have `public class AlarmReceiver extends Worker {` class...

Comment: hmm, I already test with this constraint but it does not execute immediately as you said, with the policy is REPLACE too

Comment: To OP, do not forget to set the initial delay to more than 15 minutes, if its 15 minutes or less, it will fire immediately. Happened to me. After setting to 16+ minutes, the delayed worked as excpected.

Answer (score 3):

The builder has a function `setInitialDelay`, call it as such. The default constraint is already `Constraints.NONE`, so setting it again has no result.

```
private void startwork() {
    PeriodicWorkRequest work = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(AlarmReceiver.class, 16, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setInitialDelay(16, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this)
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("workname", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, work);
}
```

As a worried potential user: do you really want to sent a notification every 16 minutes?

Comment: 16 minutes is for test only, users will choose it on app settings. I add setInitialDelay and remove setContraints but all time I open MainActivity I still have the alert from worker... Any ideas what is wrong?